# How to query RavenDB using complex query in F#

Tags: f#, nosql, ravendb

I am using RavenDB 2.0 unstable.
Is it possible to query RavenDB 2.0 with a lambda or similar technique (linq?) from F#?

Here is intent example code. I am attempting to get all the posts in last 72 hours. Its wrong, but it gets the idea across.

```
static member public GetTopPosts _ =
    use store = (new DocumentStore(Url = Docs.serverUrl, DefaultDatabase = Docs.dbName )).Initialize()
    use session = store.OpenSession()
    let result = session.Query<Post>().Where(fun x -> x.Date > DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(72,0,0))
    ...
```

How can something like this be accomplished?

Comment: The F# client is no longer supported in RavenDB 2.0.  See here: https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/66fddbc05e18d3b3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

You can find an example of this in [FAKE](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/develop/src/deploy.web/Fake.Deploy.Web.DataProviders/Fake.Deploy.Web.RavenDb/Provider.fs#L68)

In your case your query would look something like this

```
let getTopPostsAsOf date =
    use session = docStore.OpenSession()
    query {
       for post in session.Query<Post>() do
       where (post.Date > date)
       select post
    } |> Seq.toArray
```

this would then be called with

```
let result = getTopPostsAsOf (DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromHours(72))
```

A couple of things to note.

1. The DocumentStore should be created once and only once at the startup of the application.
2. Also typically only a small set of library calls can be used within the query expressions, hence why I pass in the already computed date. The reason for this is because these expression trees end up getting serialized and executed within raven db engine.